# Can I free memory passed to SysAllocString?

Tags: c++, windows, string, memory-management, bstr

When allocating a new BSTR with SysAllocString via a wchar_t* on the heap, should I then free the original wchar_t* on the heap?

So is this the right way?

```
wchar_t *hs = new wchar_t[20];
// load some wchar's into hs...
BSTR bs = SysAllocString(hs);
delete[] hs;
```

Am I supposed to call delete here to free up the memory?  Or was that memory just adoped by the BSTR?

Comment: Kind of funny - I completely misread the variables when I posted my answer (which I subsequently deleted).  I "saw" delete[] bs; instead of hs.  I must need new glasses.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As its name implies, `SysAllocString` allocates its memory, it does not "adopt" its argument's memory. BSTRs are size-prefixed *and* null-terminated, so "adopting" a c-style string is impossible, as there is no space for the size prefix.

Answer (score 13):

SysAllocString(), from the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms891285.aspx), behaves like this:

> This function allocates a new string
> and copies the passed string into it.

So, yes, once you've called SysAllocString you can free your original character array, as the data has been copied into the newly allocated BSTR.

The proper way to free a string of `wchar_t` allocated with `new[]` is to use `delete[]`.

```
wchar_t *hs = new wchar_t[20];
...
delete[] hs;
```

The proper way to free a `BSTR` is with [SysFreeString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms891288.aspx):

```
BSTR bs = SysAllocString(hs);
...
SysFreeString(bs);
```

While you're new to BSTRs, you should read [Eric's Complete Guide to BSTR Semantics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/erics-complete-guide-to-bstr-semantics).

Answer (score 4):

[The docs for `SysAllocString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms891285.aspx) are pretty clear:

> This function allocates a new string and copies the passed string into it.

The string data you pass in is copied - `SysAllocString()` doesn't use it after it's completed - you're free to deallocate or modify that buffer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `delete` the memory.

Answer (score 1):

To convert `wchar_t*` to `OLECHAR*` you need to use [`W2OLE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3%28VS.80%29.aspx) macro:

```
wchar_t *hs = new wchar_t[20];
USES_CONVERSION;
BSTR bs = SysAllocString( W2OLE(hs) );
delete[] hs; // no need in hs anymore since SysAllocString allocates memory
...

SysFreeString( bs );  // delete Sys string
```